# Calling DialogFragment from Activity resulting in "IllegalStateException: fragment not attached to Activity"

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity that has a Fragment, and I need to show a DialogFragment (which is declared public and static inside the fragment) for logging the user out.
In this dialog I need to make a server request and when it's done, the dialog must be dismissed.

The problem here is that when the server request arrives, I get the error "IllegalStateException: fragment not attached to Activity"

Is there a way to do overcome this problem?

EDIT:

This is the `logcat` output:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13849): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment LogoutDialogFragment{4256be70} not attached to Activity
E/AndroidRuntime(13849):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:836)
E/AndroidRuntime(13849):    at nl.emte.merchant.ui.EmteActivity$LogoutDialogFragment$1$1.onDataLoad(EmteActivity.java:328)
E/AndroidRuntime(13849):    at nl.emte.merchant.api.EmteApiManager$5.onPostExecute(EmteApiManager.java:212)
```

And this is the code of the `LogOutFragment` which is the `DialogFragment` that allows users to log out:

```
public static class LogoutDialogFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.logout_screen_description);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.logout_positive_button_lbl,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            EmteApiManager.getInstance().doLogout(new DataLoadListner() {

                                @Override
                                public void onError(Object errorMessage) {
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onDataLoad(Object result) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                                            IntentActions.ACTION_LOGIN);
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton(R.string.logout_negative_button_lbl,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            return builder.create();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Need more information in order to help you, if you could post some code and your logcat that would be great

Comment: @zozelfelfo there you go ;)

Comment: could you highlight `EmteActivity.java:328` please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a static class that uses the application context for the callback.

Activities and Fragments are ephemeral, so it is dangerous to rely on them to be in a good state after an asynchronous callback.

Answer (score 2):

I think you shouldn't call dismiss until after calling startActivity()